# Is there a way to specify class type for unmarshalling?

Tags: spring, kotlin, xstream

Assume I have next xml structure:

```xml
<someGlobalClass>

  <someType_WithMultipleImpl>
  </someType_WithMultipleImpl>

  <someType_WithMultipleImpl>
  </someType_WithMultipleImpl>

</someGlobalClass>
```

These two inner tags has similar tag name. But their content is slightly different, so I must implement 2 different classes. During unmarshalling only one implementation of `someType_WithMultipleImpl` is selected and all other tags are being converted to that single implementation. Is there a way to specify conversion class for XStream? Right now it is something like this

SomeType1:

```
@XStreamAlias("someType_WithMultipleImpl")
data class SomeType1{
//fields, methods, etc.
}
```

SomeType2 (that uses same tag name):

```
@XStreamAlias("someType_WithMultipleImpl")
data class SomeType2(){
//fields, methods, etc.
}
```

The real example is a bit harder, additional info can be provided if needed